# TikZ-UML bounding box too large

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I'm facing issues using TikZ-UML, as the bounding box grows unexpectedly large when I have a relation in my diagram.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
  \umlsimpleclass[x=0,y=0]{A}
  \umlsimpleclass[x=0,y=-2]{B}
  \umlinherit{B}{A}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

results in

[image]

while when I don't have any relations in my diagram there seems to be no issue:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
  \umlsimpleclass[x=0,y=0]{A}
  \umlsimpleclass[x=0,y=-2]{B}
  %\umlinherit{B}{A}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete example and tell us how you compile your code. When I compile `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
  \umlsimpleclass[x=0,y=0]{A}
  \umlsimpleclass[x=0,y=-2]{B}
  \umlinherit{B}{A}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` with `pdflatex` I fail to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Schrödinger'scat for investigating. I could resolve my issue while trying to produce an MWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I set `relation weight=2pt` inside `\tikzumlset`. I expected this to increase the line-width of relations in the first place and forgot to remove it.

Removing `relation weight` resolved my issue.